# Create deck of card using multiple enums

Tags: c#, foreach, enums

I have made the following code to create a deck of cards using 2 enums and a switch statement. I do not think the switch statement is an elegant solution. My question is, therefore: Is it possible avoid the switch statement by looping through a enum?

The variable Value31 is used to stored the value the cards have in the game of "31".

```
namespace CardGame31
{
public enum SuitPossibleValues { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades };
public enum RankPossibleValues { two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace };

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CardDeck myCardDeck = new CardDeck();
    }
}

class CardDeck
{
    List<Card> CardDeckList = new List<Card>();

    public CardDeck()
    {
        foreach (SuitPossibleValues colourPossibleValues in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SuitPossibleValues)))
        {
            foreach (RankPossibleValues namePossibleValues in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RankPossibleValues)))
            {
                Card nextCard = new Card(colourPossibleValues.ToString(), namePossibleValues.ToString());
                CardDeckList.Add(nextCard);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Card
{
    public string Colour { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Value31 { get; }

    public Card(string colour, string name)
    {
        Colour = colour;
        Name = name;

        switch (name)
        {
            case ("two"):
                Value31 = 2;
                break;
            case ("three"):
                Value31 = 3;
                break;
            case ("four"):
                Value31 = 4;
                break;
            case ("five"):
                Value31 = 5;
                break;
            case ("six"):
                Value31 = 6;
                break;
            case ("seven"):
                Value31 = 7;
                break;
            case ("eight"):
                Value31 = 8;
                break;
            case ("nine"):
                Value31 = 9;
                break;
            case ("ten"):
                Value31 = 10;
                break;
            case ("Jack"):
                Value31 = 10;
                break;
            case ("Queen"):
                Value31 = 10;
                break;
            case ("King"):
                Value31 = 10;
                break;
            case ("Ace"):
                Value31 = 11;
                break;
            default:
                throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("name", "name should have one of the following values: two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And let's say you do loop through all the enums, what then? You would still need to translate the card name into its value, so you would still need some kind of `switch`

Comment: _"Is it possible avoid the switch statement by looping through a enum?"_ -- sure, it's _possible_. See marked duplicates (among others) for discussion of different ways to represent cards in a deck without having a big switch. Personally, I favor [assigning values directly to the enums](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5352166), and disagree that using enums doesn't gain you anything. But there are other ways to do it as well, which are just as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the value directly in `enum` declaration like the following:

```
public enum RankPossibleValues { 
two =2, 
three=3, 
four=4, 
five=5, 
six=6, 
seven=7, 
eight=8, 
nine=9, 
ten=10, 
Jack=11, 
Queen=12, 
King=13, 
Ace=14 
};
```

then you can get the underlying integer value by simple `int` cast like in example shown below:

```
int _value31 = (int)RankPossibleValues.two;
```

Hope this will help.