# How do you use a return value, but don't run the whole code again?

Tags: c#, forms, return

so i am trying to create a  blackjack game, but i don't know how to get the return value from dealing the first 2 cards if a player wanted to get another card without running the whole code again and resetting the first 2 cards dealt before.
I get that i am calling for the code to be executed again, but i am wondering if anyone knows how to do it without executing the whole code, but still get the return value.

I posed the whole code so that if anyone can help me they get some sense of what I'm trying to do.

Sorry for the messy code i am new to this site so i don't know how to make it look nice. Hope anyone can help. :)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    namespace Gamble
    {
    public partial class Form2: Form
        {        
     public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Form2(string value)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblValue.Text = value;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public string value { get; set; }      
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //back
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    public int[] CardNR()
    {
        string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Downloads", "*.png");
        List<string> images = paths.ToList();
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] s = { random.Next(0, images.Count - 1), random.Next(0, images.Count - 1), random.Next(0, images.Count - 1), random.Next(0, images.Count - 1), random.Next(0, images.Count - 1), random.Next(0, images.Count - 1), random.Next(0, images.Count - 1), random.Next(0, images.Count - 1), random.Next(0, images.Count - 1), random.Next(0, images.Count - 1) };
        return s;
    }
    public int DScore(int[] s)
    {
        string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Downloads", "*.png");
        List<string> paths = images.ToList();
        string[] score = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Downloads", "*.png");
        int DealP = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Dealer1.ImageLocation = paths[s[0]];
            Dealer2.ImageLocation = paths[s[1]];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)
        {
            if (paths[s[i]] == score[0] || paths[s[i]] == score[1] || paths[s[i]] == score[2] || paths[s[i]] == score[3] || paths[s[i]] == score[40] || paths[s[i]] == score[41] || paths[s[i]] == score[42] || paths[s[i]] == score[43] || paths[s[i]] == score[44] || paths[s[i]] == score[45] || paths[s[i]] == score[46] || paths[s[i]] == score[47] || paths[s[i]] == score[48] || paths[s[i]] == score[49] || paths[s[i]] == score[50] || paths[s[i]] == score[51])
            {
                DealP += 10;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[4] || paths[s[i]] == score[5] || paths[s[i]] == score[6] || paths[s[i]] == score[7])
            {
                DealP += 2;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[8] || paths[s[i]] == score[9] || paths[s[i]] == score[10] || paths[s[i]] == score[11])
            {
                DealP += 3;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[12] || paths[s[i]] == score[13] || paths[s[i]] == score[14] || paths[s[i]] == score[15])
            {
                DealP += 4;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[16] || paths[s[i]] == score[17] || paths[s[i]] == score[18] || paths[s[i]] == score[19])
            {
                DealP += 5;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[20] || paths[s[i]] == score[21] || paths[s[i]] == score[22] || paths[s[i]] == score[23])
            {
                DealP += 6;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[24] || paths[s[i]] == score[25] || paths[s[i]] == score[26] || paths[s[i]] == score[27])
            {
                DealP += 7;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[28] || paths[s[i]] == score[29] || paths[s[i]] == score[30] || paths[s[i]] == score[31])
            {
                DealP += 8;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[32] || paths[s[i]] == score[33] || paths[s[i]] == score[34] || paths[s[i]] == score[35])
            {
                DealP += 9;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[36] || paths[s[i]] == score[37] || paths[s[i]] == score[38] || paths[s[i]] == score[39])
            {
                DealP += 11;
            }
        }       
        DP.Text = (Convert.ToString(DealP));
        return DealP;
    }
    public int PScore(int[] s)
    {
        string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Downloads", "*.png");
        List<string> paths = images.ToList();
        string[] score = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Downloads", "*.png");
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            PCard1.ImageLocation = paths[s[2]];
            PCard2.ImageLocation = paths[s[3]];
        }           
        int PlayerP = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (paths[s[i]] == score[0] || paths[s[i]] == score[1] || paths[s[i]] == score[2] || paths[s[i]] == score[3] || paths[s[i]] == score[40] || paths[s[i]] == score[41] || paths[s[i]] == score[42] || paths[s[i]] == score[43] || paths[s[i]] == score[44] || paths[s[i]] == score[45] || paths[s[i]] == score[46] || paths[s[i]] == score[47] || paths[s[i]] == score[48] || paths[s[i]] == score[49] || paths[s[i]] == score[50] || paths[s[i]] == score[51])
                {
                    PlayerP += 10;
                }
                else if (paths[s[i]] == score[4] || paths[s[i]] == score[5] || paths[s[i]] == score[6] || paths[s[i]] == score[7])
                {
                    PlayerP += 2;
                }
                else if (paths[s[i]] == score[8] || paths[s[i]] == score[9] || paths[s[i]] == score[10] || paths[s[i]] == score[11])
                {
                    PlayerP += 3;
                }
                else if (paths[s[i]] == score[12] || paths[s[i]] == score[13] || paths[s[i]] == score[14] || paths[s[i]] == score[15])
                {
                    PlayerP += 4;
                }
                else if (paths[s[i]] == score[16] || paths[s[i]] == score[17] || paths[s[i]] == score[18] || paths[s[i]] == score[19])
                {
                    PlayerP += 5;
                }
                else if (paths[s[i]] == score[20] || paths[s[i]] == score[21] || paths[s[i]] == score[22] || paths[s[i]] == score[23])
                {
                    PlayerP += 6;
                }
                else if (paths[s[i]] == score[24] || paths[s[i]] == score[25] || paths[s[i]] == score[26] || paths[s[i]] == score[27])
                {
                    PlayerP += 7;
                }
                else if (paths[s[i]] == score[28] || paths[s[i]] == score[29] || paths[s[i]] == score[30] || paths[s[i]] == score[31])
                {
                    PlayerP += 8;
                }
                else if (paths[s[i]] == score[32] || paths[s[i]] == score[33] || paths[s[i]] == score[34] || paths[s[i]] == score[35])
                {
                    PlayerP += 9;
                }
                else if (paths[s[i]] == score[36] || paths[s[i]] == score[37] || paths[s[i]] == score[38] || paths[s[i]] == score[39])
                {
                    PlayerP += 11;
                }
            }
        PP.Text = (Convert.ToString(PlayerP));
        return PlayerP;
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblValue.Text = value;
        this.Hide();
    }
    private void DealCards_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DScore(CardNR());
        PScore(CardNR());            
    }
    public int HitCard(int[] s,int PlayerP)
    {
        string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Downloads", "*.png");
        List<string> paths = images.ToList();
        string[] score = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Downloads", "*.png");
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            PCard3.ImageLocation = paths[s[4]];
        }
        int HitPlayerP = 0;
        for (int i = 4; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (paths[s[i]] == score[0] || paths[s[i]] == score[1] || paths[s[i]] == score[2] || paths[s[i]] == score[3] || paths[s[i]] == score[40] || paths[s[i]] == score[41] || paths[s[i]] == score[42] || paths[s[i]] == score[43] || paths[s[i]] == score[44] || paths[s[i]] == score[45] || paths[s[i]] == score[46] || paths[s[i]] == score[47] || paths[s[i]] == score[48] || paths[s[i]] == score[49] || paths[s[i]] == score[50] || paths[s[i]] == score[51])
            {
                HitPlayerP += 10;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[4] || paths[s[i]] == score[5] || paths[s[i]] == score[6] || paths[s[i]] == score[7])
            {
                HitPlayerP += 2;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[8] || paths[s[i]] == score[9] || paths[s[i]] == score[10] || paths[s[i]] == score[11])
            {
                HitPlayerP += 3;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[12] || paths[s[i]] == score[13] || paths[s[i]] == score[14] || paths[s[i]] == score[15])
            {
                HitPlayerP += 4;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[16] || paths[s[i]] == score[17] || paths[s[i]] == score[18] || paths[s[i]] == score[19])
            {
                HitPlayerP += 5;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[20] || paths[s[i]] == score[21] || paths[s[i]] == score[22] || paths[s[i]] == score[23])
            {
                HitPlayerP += 6;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[24] || paths[s[i]] == score[25] || paths[s[i]] == score[26] || paths[s[i]] == score[27])
            {
                HitPlayerP += 7;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[28] || paths[s[i]] == score[29] || paths[s[i]] == score[30] || paths[s[i]] == score[31])
            {
                HitPlayerP += 8;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[32] || paths[s[i]] == score[33] || paths[s[i]] == score[34] || paths[s[i]] == score[35])
            {
                HitPlayerP += 9;
            }
            else if (paths[s[i]] == score[36] || paths[s[i]] == score[37] || paths[s[i]] == score[38] || paths[s[i]] == score[39])
            {
                HitPlayerP += 11;
            }
        }
        PlayerP += HitPlayerP;
        PP.Text = (Convert.ToString(PlayerP));
        return HitPlayerP;
    }
    private void Hit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HitCard(CardNR(),PScore(CardNR()));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  Have you tried cutting your code down to a [simple repro case](stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're having?  It'll be easier for people to help you they don't have to wrangle quite so many lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of literal comparisons within your program that are unneeded. I recommend implementing a class for all your cards like T.K. answered here: [Best way to represent game card class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352079/best-way-to-represent-game-card-class-in-c-sharp)

```
using System.Drawing;

public class Card
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public enum SuitType
    {
        Clubs, Spades, Hearts, Diamonds
    }
    public SuitType Suit { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public Card(int value, SuitType suit, Image image)
    {
        Suit = suit;
        Image = image;
        Value = value;
    }
    public Card(string input)
    {
        if (input == null || input.Length < 2 || input.Length > 2)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        switch (input[0])
        {
            case 'C': case 'c':
                Suit = SuitType.Clubs;
                break;
            case 'S': case 's':
                Suit = SuitType.Spades;
                break;
            case 'H': case 'h':
                Suit = SuitType.Hearts;
                break;
            case 'D': case 'd':
                Suit = SuitType.Diamonds;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        int uncheckedValue = (int)input[1];
        if (uncheckedValue > 14 || uncheckedValue < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        Value = uncheckedValue;
    }
    public string encode()
    {
        string encodedCard = "";
        switch (Suit)
        {
            case SuitType.Clubs:
                encodedCard += 'c';
                break;
            case SuitType.Spades:
                encodedCard += 's';
                break;
            case SuitType.Hearts:
                encodedCard += 'h';
                break;
            case SuitType.Diamonds:
                encodedCard += 'd';
                break;
        }
        encodedCard += (char) Value;
        return encodedCard;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string output = "";
        if (Value > 10)
        {
            switch (Value)
            {
                case 11:
                    output += "Jack";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    output += "Queen";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    output += "King";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    output += "Ace";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            output += Value;
        }
        output += " of " + System.Enum.GetName(typeof(SuitType), Suit);
        return output;
    }
}
```

I made some slight edits so that you could include your pictures for each card. You can then run something like this to populate the deck:

```
public static List<Card> Deck;
    private static void Main()
    {
        Deck = new List<Card>();
        SuitType? Suit = null;
        int Value;
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 13; j++)
            {
                Suit = i switch
                {
                    0 => SuitType.Clubs,
                    1 => SuitType.Spades,
                    2 => SuitType.Hearts,
                    3 => SuitType.Diamonds,
                    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
                };
                Value = j;
                Deck.Add(new Card(Value, Suit, System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("//PATH HERE//")));
            }
        }
    }
```

You'll then have a List of cards that you can use to get both the value and suit from. Make a seperate list entitled "Used" or something like that and move cards from one to the other to keep track of what cards have already been used. That should allow you to "hit" by drawing a random, unused card in the deck and afterwards discarding it to another list. That should give you a way forward to move past your original problem.

Comment: Should i rename the pictures? Or is there a specific order they should be in?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2019, and it says there is something wrong when you defined public suit. It says that 'Suit' does not exist in the current context.
So how would i get around this? Should there be an int, or string between public suit?

Comment: And also...I am using C# 8.0

Comment: Whoops, left a bit of psydocode in there when I posted the answer. You should be able to put `public SuitType Suit { get; set; }` instead to solve that issue. For the images, you can either create a dynamic path based on the name of the card created, or you can name them so that the loop goes through them in the same order that it will go through the cards.

Comment: oh well, thank you. and I was wondering, is there any other way I could populate my deck because the code you posted is not C# 8.0+, so it doesn't work with what I am working with.